# Why is the Tweet button cutoff?

Tags: html, css

On this page: http://socialadr.com/get/begin06 in the top right...

I can't figure out why the Tweet button has no bottom border.  I've played around with the CSS height, width, padding, margin, but nothing seems to help.

[image: Social buttons]

I'm using Chrome in Windows 8 64-bit.

Any ideas?

Comment: Which browser?  I see it correctly.

Comment: Looks fine in Chrome on Windows.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know which browser you're using, but looking at it, it seems only to be cut, if you're zoomed in. Try reseting your zoom.

But yeah, it seems the twitter widget indeed has a problem using zoom (containing div#widget cuts off part of content, due to size is wrong and overflow is set to hidden)

Comment: By the way, I've tested it both with Chrome and Safari, and zoom problem appears in both.

Comment: You are correct!  I have default 125% zoom in Chrome.  Good catch!  Not sure why everyone down-voted my question though, I thought it was worded decently lol.

Comment: I think the problem was it was missing a lot of information on how to reproduce the error. Like which browser :)